# Unix way to create bi-directional pipes or anything which acts like that?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, serial-port, named-pipes

I would need a bi-directional file system based (ie like a device node, named socket, named pipe, or something like that) interprocess communication possibility under Linux (and maybe other UNIX systems as well), let's say similar to a serial port, ie you can open `/dev/ttyS0` for read/write  and you can read/write it with *any* tool (including a plain `cat` command) basically, just in my case the other part is not hardware (a serial port), but another but totally unrelated process. Yes, I've already read similar questions on SO, however I'm still not sure if there is *other* similar solution, if named pipes do not so suit my needs here.

What I can see:

- named pipe/FIFO is not a a solution because it's uni-directional (at least on some UNIX-like systems, including Linux), two named pipes (one for RX and one for TX) are not a solution
- (named) sockets are not solution as they need special care, I can't just echo "into" it for example, but I need to connect() etc, so I would need a custom client to interact with (see later)
- I'm a bit unsure about socketpair() since it creates two connected sockets, but even that, the other process need special preparation still (the previous problem in my list)
- `openpty()` like tricks can be solution (and using then `/dev/pts/...` by the client, I am not sure on OSX though), however it's ugly, not so portable ...
- Solutions like a kernel module is not a solution since it's not portable at all, and requires root access anyway
- not file-system based IPC possibilities are not solution for me either, because the nature of the problem

The best way would be a bi-directional named pipe (one process writes it, the other can read, and vice-versa, if it's half-duplex, it's not so much a problem though), which works on all UNIX-like systems including at least Linux and OSX, however I couldn't find anything which works like this.

What I would like is to have a way to emulate (from user space only) something like a serial port, so I can even use it with a simple terminal client (however of course ioctl's to set up serial parameters won't work, that's not a problem!), or I can simply write/read it with `echo mmmmm > ...` or `cat ...`. I would need it for an emulator (of a computer) provides something like the serial port of a real machine, so I can interact with the emulated machine through it. I can't use other tools (like `socat` and using named sockets, or even TCP/IP, or whatever) since I also have a closed source client software I cannot change, it expects a single filename as the "serial port device", however I've tested that it does not fail on various serial port related ioctl() calls fortunately (it would work on named pipes, just the uni-directionality is my problem then), so I need to solve "only" this problem, and it would work.

Comment: I can't think of any other solution than using pseudo terminals either. But I think that could really be a solution for you, if I've correctly understood the problem. OSX portability should be possible as there are BSD pseudo terminals too

Comment: I'm not convinced that what you are wanting can be done — which is probably why you are unable to find anything that does it.  How does the second process know which way to connect things — should it be responding to the first process, or starting anew?  How would a third concurrent connection be handled?

Comment: No concurrency. In fact, from the view point of emulated machine it's a (emulated) "serial port like entity" (though without any settings like baud rate, etc) so there can't be more client, only a single one. It's not a problem that it won't work if there are more clients trying to connect, since it wouldn't work with a real serial port either. So the first client wins, but it shouldn't happen either to connect more ... Simple (named) socket is nice, I can see minicom supports `-D unix#/tmp/socket` however this is problematic that the custom client I mentioned above does not allow this.

Comment: I've also thought about using socket with AF_UNIX and SOCK_DGRAM. I am not sure what happens then (odd errno values ...) just I thought about it, since SOCK_DGRAM with internet protocols usually means the connection-less UDP, so I thought I can save the connect() stuff with a named socket as well, but it seems it's not that ...

Comment: socketpair() gives you a pair of already connected sockets, aleviating the need to `connect(2)` them.  Where did you get that you have to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only system objects that allow you to `read(2)` and `write(2)` on each descriptor individually are the socket and the pty. Those are the only objects that have two queues for sending and receiving data.  All the other *pipe* things have only one, and as you receive a pair of descriptors (for unnamed pipes for example) what you write will be received immediately if you read it next.

I don't recommend the use of the pty interface in this case, because as you have said, you have to do some housekeeping before being able to transmit and you have to deal with device parameters (like `termios` config, baudrate and character interpretations at the device level)

`getsocketpair(3)` is a library function that already gives you a pair of **already connected sockets**, and allows you to specify the type of sockets (network sockets, unix sockets, etc) you like in the call.

```
int res, sfds[2];
res = getsocketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sfds);
```

will return `0` in case of success and two already connected sockets in `sfds` array.  In BSD systems (as OS/X is derived from), `getsocketpair(2)` is a system call that allows the kernel to select an efficient version (as the example shows) that don't have the overhead imposed by networking protocols.

## NOTE

As you say in the comments, it's probable that your programs not only does `read(2)` and `write(2)` calls, but is a program that also gets raw input from the user (like switching no echo mode to get a password or getting **raw** input as interactive programs, like `vi(1)` or `emacs(1)` do)

In that case, I suggest you to download my program [`slowtty`](http://github.com/mojadita/slowtty.git) and study and modify it to work for you.  It does exactly what you want.  It allocates a pair of `pty`s and does input/output.  It also requires you to use a tty line, but only because it copies the terminal settings from your stdin to the pty line.  It's a simple program, designed just to teach people how to use the `pty(7)` interface, and it works fine in FreeBSD, Mac/OS X, and linux.  As such, the program slows tty input/output to the baudrate adjusted in the slave pty, so it allows you to see output as if you were using an old serial tty line.  The slowdown is made in a separate routine, so it can be easily eliminated from the source code.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure if it resolves my problem, ie my closed source client I have won't do "connect" to anything it wants to open the given path as a file ... And I have to use that to communicate with a process ... That client was designed originally to used with serial port like with `/dev/ttyS0 `, it's my problem here, that I can't change the client ... The only easy part, that it seems the client does not care if serial parameter setup ioctl etc cannot be done so I can "fake" other file system based objects as well, but not ones need to be connect()-ed first, it'd mean change client code!

Comment: You receive two **already connected** socket descriptors, so you don't need to `connect(2)` them.  Those socket descriptors are ready to send data to each other in both directions, and with no character translation, as would happen with a pseudo-tty.  That your client was designed to work with a terminal was not in your original question, then probably the pty solution is better.  Have you dug on `expect(1)` utility?  It communicates with programs that have such requirements.

Comment: `expect(1)` allows you to talk to a terminal based (possibly interactive) program.  It sends messages to it and receives and acts upon the responses... and no programming at all.

Comment: My original question that I have a client which needs a file name opened as a normal file and using only read/write. Ie a serial port (/dev/ttyS? for example) without prior setup for serial parameters. I need to use this client since is has extra capabilities then to interpret the communication. Just now I don't want to talk a hw via serial port but with an emulation of that, and a user process. socketpairs - imho - connected together, but to connect from another process to one of them, still needs connect, or am I wrong here?

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt, you say **ie a serial port**. I understand *"for example"*, from the context you mention.  Also, requiring a terminal normally implies that your program is also using the `isatty(3)` function, which does also some `ioctl(2)` system calls, which are serial line dependant (for example to switch to *raw mode*, as happens with programs like `vi(1)`)  You don't mention in your question any of these, so in case your program **only does `read(2)` and `write(2)`** it suffices with `getsocketpair(2)` system call.

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt, ...  In case your program **needs a terminal line** (because it stops on the first `ioctl(2)` call) then **you need a pty solution**.  Explain yourself, and more help can be given.  By the way, `expect(1)` tool solves all these in a scripting way, allowing you to control programs that **do need** a serial line.

Comment: no, as I wrote in my post, _fortunately_ though it tries to set up serial parameters, it can live without it, if it fails. I only need a file system based entity which behaves like a bi-directional pipe between two different processes and can be used with plain open/read/write without fancy stuffs, like needing to connect() first, etc. But I am more or less sure that I should re-implement the (closed source / binary only) client software, it's much faster now it seems than trying to find a clumsy solution for the odd problem :) So I can use then anything I want :D

Comment: I'm more or less sure now that my original question cannot be solved too much with a generic and portable solution. I give up the original plan of mine and instead I will write a better client. Thanks for the answer :)